# How to open a rendered animation?

Tags: rendering

I just sat through an hour or so to render my first 5 second animation. Now how can I access and play my file? The default folder it should be in (/tmp) only has one Blender related file, 296_autosave.blend. This is a noob question but there didn't seem to be an answer for it yet.

Comment: Depends on the OS...? Click on the folder icon under *Output Properties (Printer Icon) > Output Panel > Output Path*. What file type?

Comment: I'm Using OSX. I don't understand your question sorry! Do you mean the folder path? There's no file type, by default it said /tmp

Answer (score 4):

Go to *Render > View Animation*  or  use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F11</kbd>:

[image: render > view animation]

To know the output location check Output Path in Output Properties. (You may have changed this accidentally)

[image: output properties > output > output path]

edit:

On Windows 10, the full path to output folder is displayed on the title bar of animation viewer[image]

Comment: Thanks! I figured out this much myself but I can't locate the /tmp folder on my computer. I accessed some temp folder by typing open $TMPDIR command Terminal but it didn't have the frame files so it's probably incorrect.

Comment: @mntblnk edited the answer. hope this helps.

Comment: I wish it did, but unfortunately not. I'm on Mac and I can see the path just fine, it's just that I can't access the folder.